# Distributions of positive definite matrices other than Wishart?

Tags: matrices, statistics, probability-distributions, positive-definite, random-matrices

Wishart is a distribution of positive definite matrices. However, Wishart's variance is too large for me. (I'm using it as a proposal for my M-H algorithm, and it gives very small acceptance rate when df is the same as dimension of the matrix).

So, I wonder is there any other distributions for positive definite matrices so that I can have a better control over the variance of the matrices?

Comment: You can just scale the Wishart distribution to have whatever variance you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let's say my current distribution is Wishart(n, V). In order to keep the mean, nV, unchanged, I change the distribution to Wishart(10n,V/10). Now the distribution has its original variance divided by 10. Is this correct?

Comment: That is a more complicated operation than what I meant by "scaling." I literally mean take a Wishart-distributed matrix $M$ and then divide it by $k$. This divides the variance by $k^2$. If you want the same mean $\sigma$ then take $\frac{M - \sigma}{k} + \sigma$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.